# excel vba set workbook w/ path, reference worksheets within - run time error 9er

Tags: excel, vba

newbie trying this for the first time... i'm getting errors, mostly "subscript out of range". Currently issue highlights -> Set ICE line

Goal of this, I'd like to learn how to set workbooks w/ a path, and reference worksheets within. Then ultimately clear existing data and replace it with renewed data from the other workbook. wouldn't be surprised if more errors exist... Really appreciate your help!

```
Dim ICE As Workbook
Dim RTL As Workbook
Dim IDS As Workbook
Dim ICEFile As String
    ICEFile = "C:\Users\m\Documents\Rental Projects\Ice Report\ICE Report.xlsx"
Dim RTLFile As String
    RTLFile = "C:\Users\m\Documents\Rental Projects\Ice Report\OpenRentalAgreements.xlsx"
Dim IDSFile As String
    IDSFile = "C:\Users\m\Documents\Rental Projects\Ice Report\ActiveIDsByManagers.xlsx"
Set ICE = Workbooks(ICEFile)
Set RTL = Workbooks(RTLFile)
Set IDS = Workbooks(IDSFile)
Dim ICERR As Worksheet: Set ICERR = ICE.Sheets("RRDataINPUT")
Dim ICEID As Worksheet: Set ICEID = ICE.Sheets("IDsReconINPUT")
       
ICE.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ICERR.Range("AH:BU").Select
Selection.Clear
ICEID.Range("M:AK").Select
Selection.Clear
ICERR.Range("AH:BU").Value = IDS.Range("B:Z").Value
ICEID.Range("M:AK").Value = RTL.Range("A:AN").Value
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, firstly replace

```
Set ICE = Workbooks(ICEFile)
```

with

```
Set ICE = Workbooks.Open(ICEFile)
```

Only an open Workbook can be referenced. If they are already open, their name must be used, not their full name. This can be obtained in many ways. I prefer the next one:

```
     ICEFile = Split(ICEFile, "\")(UBound(Split(ICEFile, "\")))
```

**Do the same with the next two code lines**...

When you debug, it is not appropriate to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. You need to see what is happening, running the code line by line (pressing F8 in VBE...).

```
ICERR.Range("AH:BU").Value = IDS.Range("B:Z").Value
```

will not work. Both ranges must have **the same number of rows (they have) and columns**...

Try `Debug.Print Range("AH:BU").Columns.count, Range("B:Z").Columns.count` and see what it returns in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G` in IDE).

The same will happen for

```
ICEID.Range("M:AK").Value = RTL.Range("A:AN").Value
```

because of the same reason.

Try `Range("M:AK").Columns.count, Range("A:AN").Columns.count` and see what it returns in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G` in IDE).

Finally, it is not necessary to select/activate anything in order to perform such actions...

Comment: @Feldy: Didn't I answer your question? Is it something you did not understand?